# Prove that $S^n$ is a strong deformation retract of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1} \setminus \{(0,...,0)\}$

Tags: algebraic-topology, spheres

> Prove that $S^n$ (n-dimensional sphere with unit radius) is a strong deformation retract of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1} \setminus\{(0,...,0)\}$

This is my attempt:

Consider $f : S^n \to \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \setminus\{(0,...,0)\}$ as the *inclusion map* and $g : \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \setminus\{(0,...,0)\} \to S^n$ as the map defined as

$$g(y) = \frac{y}{\operatorname{norm}(y)} \ ,\ y \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \setminus\{(0,...,0)\}$$

Clearly both are continuous, and that $g|_{S^n}$ is an identity map, hence $g$ is a retraction.

But when I am faced with proving that $f \circ g$ is homotopic relative $S^n$ to the identity map $1:\mathbb{R}^{n+1} \setminus\{(0,...,0)\} \to \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \setminus\{(0,...,0)\}$, I get stuck.

Are the maps I defined wrong from the start? If they aren't, can someone give me a hint on how to construct the homotopy relative $S^n$? Thank you.

P.S. I'm rather new in Algebraic Topology so there is a lot that I don't know or still do not understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So $f:S^n\to\Bbb R^{n+1}∖\{(0,...,0)\}$ is the inclusion and $g:\Bbb R^{n+1}∖\{(0,...,0)\}\to S^n$ is the retraction. We want a homotopy starting with the identity $\text{id}$ end ending at $fg$. Since for any vector $x$ there is a straight line between $x$ and $fg(x)=x/||x||$, one natural way would be the homotopy sliding each point along this line segment, that is the map 
$$(x,t)\mapsto t\frac x{||x||}+(1-t)x$$
Another map is suggested by the idea that each point $x$ starts at $\dfrac x1$ and ends at $\dfrac x{||x||}$, so in between we should divide $x$ by something between $1$ and $||x||$. This leads to
$$(x,t)\mapsto \frac x{t||x||+(1-t)}$$
I leave it to you to check that these maps are well-defined and continuous, then choose your favorite one ;-)